# Excluir ids específicos em querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css-seletores

Quero pegar a quantidades de elementos vindo de um array:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select,input,textarea');
alert(Object.keys(arr).length);//19
```

Dentro do array tenho 4 elementos a excluir, onde tento usar o seletor `:not`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select,input,textarea,input:not[type="hidden",input:not[id="input_up_img_perfil"],input:not[id="sub_img_perfil"],');
alert(Object.keys(arr).length);//19
```

Qual a sintaxe correta para eleimnar esses elementos da busca?

Comment: Talvez te ajude: [How to use querySelectorAll only for elements that have a specific attribute set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777684/how-to-use-queryselectorall-only-for-elements-that-have-a-specific-attribute-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sintaxe correta seria:

```js
var nos = document.querySelectorAll('select,textarea,input:not([type="hidden"]):not(#input_up_img_perfil):not(#sub_img_perfil)');
console.log(nos);
```

```html
<select name="sel1">
</select>
<select name="sel2">
</select>
<select name="sel3">
</select>

<input type="text" class="inp1">
<input type="text" class="inp2" id="input_up_img_perfil">
<input type="text" class="inp3" id="sub_img_perfil">
<input type="hidden" class="inp4">
<input type="hidden" class="inp5">

<textarea class="ta1"></textarea>
<textarea class="ta2"></textarea>
```

Não inclua `input` sozinho antes porque será selecionado todos e os `:not`s posteriores serão ignorados:

```
                                    ↓
document.querySelectorAll('select,input,textarea,input:not...
```

Você deve referenciar a tag apenas uma vez:

```
     ↓
...input:not([type="hidden"]):not(#input_up_img_perfil):not(#sub_img_perfil)
```

As propriedades do elemento que quer selecionar, você inclui dentro de parênteses `()`.

Comment: Legal, vlw man....